# Part of jQuery code not working

Tags: jquery, text, mouseover

It seems that after *mmenu* plugin no jQuery code works. Can someone suggest what's the issue? The thing I want is to force text inside *span* tag change on hover; however, it's not happening. I tried to use some other functions, but they don't work as well. Am I missing brackets or something?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-menu").mmenu({
        extensions: [
            "border-none",
            "effect-slide-menu",
            "pageshadow",
            "theme-white"
        ],
        navbar: {
            add: false
        }
    });

    $("#skype-change").mouseover(function() {
        $("#skype-change span").text("Whatever I wish to see here!");
    });
});
```

And a bit of HTML.

```
<p class="text-close" id="skype-change"><span><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works now. I've changed nothing and waited about 25 mins for that code to work for unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `#skype-change` `p` tag inside the `#my-menu`?

What if you use delegate event?
E.g.

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "#skype-change", function()
{
  [...]
});
```

Comment: Sorry, had to mention this: those are very different parts of the code.  #my-menu and and #skype-change are not related.